# Sum value from gridview cells and display it using label

Tags: c#, gridview

```
string total;
int totalmarks = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {

                int rowcount = this.GridView1.Rows.Count;

                for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++)
                {
                    total = row.Cells[3].Text;
                    totalmarks = Convert.ToInt32(total);

                    totalmarks +=totalmarks ;
                }


            }

            totalmarksLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(totalmarks);
```

I use that portion of code to get the value from cell[3] for every rows in gridview. Then i try to sum up every value from every row and display it using label.  however, when i run my code, the value displayed is 510 where it supposed to be 170.

** value for row [1], row[2], row[3] are 60, 30 and 80 respectively.

i found the problem, i have an extra loop. after correcting it, the value shown is 160 instead of 170. the mystery being where is the other '10' disappear?? its 3 a.m here in Malaysia and i'am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected my code like below. and it works

```
int totalMarks=0;

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {

                total = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Text);

               totalMarks = totalMarks + total;



        }



        totalMarks Label.Text = Convert.ToString(totalMarks );
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the formatted value rendered to html. instead to use the underlying data item and total the value.

```
var data = getdata();
grid.datasource = data;
grid.databind();
total.text = data.select(d=>d.value).sum().tostring();
```

Comment: i corrected my code, i didn't realize there is an extra loop. however he value shown is 160 instead of 170.where is the other '10' disappear?

Answer (score 0):

best way to find out, set a breakpoint on your application. then run in debugger mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = row.Cells[3].Text;
```

Should be

```
total = row.Cells[i].Text;
```